# Ubuntu pointer moves on its own

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I plugged my razer mouse into my ubuntu laptop today. I did not like the preset sensitivity and acceleration:

```
benjamin@benjamin-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~$ xinput --list-props 12
Device 'Razer  Razer Orochi 2013':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (260): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (261):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (262):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (263):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (250):    5426, 57
    Device Node (251):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (264): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (266):  0
    Axis Labels (267):  "Rel X" (143), "Rel Y" (144), "Rel Vert Wheel" (259)
    Button Labels (268):    "Button Left" (136), "Button Middle" (137), "Button Right" (138), "Button Wheel Up" (139), "Button Wheel Down" (140), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (142), "Button Side" (254), "Button Extra" (255), "Button Forward" (256), "Button Back" (257), "Button Task" (258), "Button Unknown" (253), "Button Unknown" (253), "Button Unknown" (253), "Button Unknown" (253)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (269):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (270):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (271): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (272): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (273):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (274):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (275):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (276):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (277):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (278):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (279): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (280):  0
```

So I edited those properties with:

```
benjamin@benjamin-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~$ xinput --set-prop 12 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
benjamin@benjamin-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~$ xinput --set-prop 12 "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Everything was working great. After a few minutes the mouse started acting strange. It would make short jerky motions and clicks. I tried unplugging the mouse and this continued. This makes me think maybe it was a touchpad issue? At the time my laptop was closed and I was attached to an external monitor.

For completion:

```
benjamin@benjamin-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer  Razer Orochi 2013                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer  Razer Orochi 2013                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Err... Reboot the computer and [use the mouse settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zAabK.png)?